# Two forms on one page - input types transferring

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments

I have two forms on one page to handle a choice of 2 stripe subscriptions (basic and advanced) and I'm using javascript to submit each form on click of the button as below:

For the basic plan:

```
<form id="payment_form_basic" action="" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="subscription_purchase_non_trial" value="subscription_purchase_non_trial_basic" />
<button id="pricing__action_grey">Choose Plan</button>
</form>

<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>

<script>
// ******************************************
// ****** Basic Plan Form Processor *********
// ******************************************

var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
key: '<?php echo $stripe['publishable_key']; ?>',
image: 'https://example.com/example.png',
locale: 'auto',
allowRememberMe: 'false',
token: function(token) {
$('#payment_form_basic').append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token.id));
$('#payment_form_basic').append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeEmail" />').val(token.email));
$("#payment_form_basic").submit();
}
});

document.getElementById('pricing__action_grey').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
// Open Checkout with further options:
handler.open({
name: 'Basic',
description: 'example description',
zipCode: true,
amount: 10
});
e.preventDefault();
});

// Close Checkout on page navigation:
window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
handler.close();
});
</script>
```

And for the advanced plan:

```
<form id="payment_form_advanced" action="" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="subscription_purchase_non_trial" value="subscription_purchase_non_trial_advanced" />
<input type="hidden" name="subscription_type" value="advanced" />
<button id="pricing__action">Choose Plan</button>
</form>

<script>
// ******************************************
// ****** Advanced Plan Form Processor ******
// ******************************************

var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
key: '<?php echo $stripe['publishable_key']; ?>',
image: 'https://example.com/example.png',
locale: 'auto',
allowRememberMe: 'false',
token: function(token) {
$('#payment_form_advanced').append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token.id));
$('#payment_form_advanced').append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeEmail" />').val(token.email));
//$('#payment_form_advanced').append($('<input type="hidden" name="subscription_type" value="advanced" />'));
$("#payment_form_advanced").submit();

}
});

document.getElementById('pricing__action').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
// Open Checkout with further options:
handler.open({
name: 'Advanced',
description: 'example descript',
zipCode: true,
amount: 12
});
e.preventDefault();
});

// Close Checkout on page navigation:
window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
handler.close();
});
</script>
```

I'm trying to use the subscription_type field in the advanced form as a switch when the page posts onto itself to determine whether to process the basic plan price or the advanced plan however the form still post the "advanced" subscription type through when the basic form is submitted, it seems like the advanced from always overwrites the basic form, at list that' what appears to happen when I print the post variables received, which makes no sense to me. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: show your js code

Comment: Yes it will. Especially if your submitting on itself. Instead change the name of each "subscription". Maybe "subscription_basic" and "subscription_advanced"

Comment: Actually,  one should not overwrite the other. I ran your code and it works as it should. I replace $ with getElementById, and so use vanilla js, but that should not make a diff. I am using Firefox. `vardump()` your `$_POST` with each submit and update your post.

Comment: Its working fine when you submit form for basic it send only basic details subscription:subscription
subscription_type:basic     and incase of advance it will send advance details: subscription:subscription
subscription_type:advanced

Comment: Could you please  show all scripts what exactly you are doing ?

Comment: you have two inputs with the duplicated names - though they are in different forms ... hmmm, makes you think

Comment: `subscription:subscription` `subscription_type:basic` OR `subscription:subscription` `subscription_type:advanced` are what you have it set up to submit. What else are you expecting? To make this a good question, show what output you are getting and what output you are expecting.

Comment: I'm with @JaromandaX on this. Maybe give the input fields unique names and id's, my guess is that'd help.

Comment: I've pasted all the code (php and javascript) anyone got any idea why the basic form button press always seems to fire the advanced form?

Answer (score 0):

Seems I needed to wrap all the script (in each scenario) in the on click function, that way the advanced settings didn't over write the basic settings for stripe. Hopefully this is a robust approach.